# Решение СЛАУ методом Барейса

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада

Всем добрый день! Стоит задача решить слау, при этом число строк и столбцов не обязательно одинаковое (решаю задачу с тимуса 1580: http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1580). Матрица коэффициентов имеет значения только 1 или 0, а правые части могут быть любыми. Это завело меня в тупик связанный с тем, что на некоторые входные данные алгоритм дает NaN. Я разобрался что это из-за того что при приведении к треугольному виду используется деление на 0. Подскажите пожалуйста, как обойти это? Я нашел что есть т.н. метод Барейса, но литературы про него крайне мало. Помогите исправить код, буду очень благодарен:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //INPUT
        string[] inLine = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        int N = int.Parse(inLine[0]);   //N - число неизвестных (число студентов)
        int M = int.Parse(inLine[1]);   //M - число уравнений (число пар студентов пришедших к декану)
        double[,] A = new double[M, N+1];   //A - матрица коэффициентов
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            inLine = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            A[i, int.Parse(inLine[0]) - 1] = 1;
            A[i, int.Parse(inLine[1]) - 1] = 1;
            A[i, N] = int.Parse(inLine[2]);
        }
        if (M < N)
            Console.WriteLine("IMPOSSIBLE");
        else
        {
            double[] result = GaussMethod(A);
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
                if (double.IsNaN(result[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IMPOSSIBLE");
                    return;
                }
            for (int j = 0; j < result.Length; j++) 
                Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", result[j]);
        }
    }

    static double[] GaussMethod(double[,] a)
    {
        //найти размер матрицы
        int width = a.GetLength(1);
        int height = a.GetLength(0);

        double[] x = new double[height]; //массив решений уравнения
        //инициализация массива корней уравнения
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) 
        {
            x[i] = a[i, width - 1];
        }

        //приведение матрицы к треугольному виду
        double m;
        for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++) 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < height; j++) 
            {
                m = a[j, i] / a[i, i];
                for (int k = 0; k < height; k++) 
                    a[j, k] -= m * a[i, k]; 
                x[j] -= m * x[i];
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
            a[i, width - 1] = x[i];


        for (int i = height - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < width - 1; j++) 
            {
                x[i] -= i != j ? a[i, j] * x[j] : 0;
            }
            x[i] = x[i] / a[i, i];
        }           
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: а чем вам метод Гаусса не угодил? Реализуется легко, только надо не забывать переставлять уравнения в матрице. Тогда и деления на ноль не будет.

Comment: а как именно их переставлять? если видим что грядет ноль в знаменателе, то ищем ту где нуля в этом столбце нет и меняем? а что если такой строки нет? тогда не совместна система?

Comment: ну вот, теорию вроде знаете, осталось сделать =) хотя, по поводу не совместности системы, не уверен, уточните.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательнее посмотрите на вот этот участок кода:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++) 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < height; j++) 
        {
            m = a[j, i] / a[i, i];
```

Вы не проверяете знаменатель на 0 - отсюда и NaNы. Вам нужно среди всех строк в качестве опорной выбрать ту, которая не имеет ноля в i-м столбце, после чего поменять ее с i-й строкой.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, почему Ваш алгоритм даёт на некоторые данные значения `NAN`. В теории численных решений СЛАУ есть такое понятие, как устойчивость системы. Вот именно здесь возникает Ваша проблема судя по всему. Для начала, я расскажу это на примере [LU-разложения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [LUP-разложения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LUP-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Я полагаю, что Ваш метод Барейса здесь ни при чём! Как я вижу, в вашем решении реализуется именно LU-разложение. А нужно Вам LUP-разложение. Попробуйте реализовать его. Если не зайдёт, пишите.

Перед тем как начать, скажем, что существуют такие системы, в которых значения в матрице сильно различаются. Например:

```
1    0    1
1000 1    1000
1    1000 500
```

Разумеется, с аналитической точки зрения всё у нас прекрасно. Но с точки зрения вычислений -- всё плохо. Если рассматривать учитывать тот факт, что накапливается погрешность.

Понятно, что от перемены мест уравнений ничего не изменится с аналитической точки зрения. Но от порядка операций зависит очень много, коль скоро мы говорим о нарастании погрешности. Поэтому при численном решении СЛАУ на машине порядок следования уравнений очень важен!

Теперь, для того, чтобы продемонстрировать, что такое устойчивость, рассмотрим 2 уравнения (здесь Вас должен постигнуть **катарсис**):

[image: Неустойчивая СЛАУ]
[image: Фиг. 1]

Тут же рассмотрим вторую СЛАУ:

[image: Устойчивая СЛАУ]
[image: Фиг. 2]

Видно, что чем ближе к параллельности прямые, тем меньше будут отличаться коэффициенты. То же самое будет и в пространствах большей размерности. Другое дело, что это представить нельзя для n > 3.

Задачу об определении "качества" матрицы также формулируют, как вопрос о плохой обусловленности матрицы. Это понятие тесно связано с понятием [нормы матрицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) в некотором нормированном пространстве. [Норма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) -- это обобщение понятия длины вектора для абстрактных пространств (есть также, схожее определение, называемое [метрикой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) -- длина). Вообще говоря, в многомерных пространствах понятие вектора и точки смазываются. Это, вероятно, происходит потому что точка -- это неудобный объект. Его сложно обобщить. Вектор же обобщить проще. Поэтому часто говорят о точке, как о радиус-векторе. В таком случае, можно искать и расстояние между векторами при помощи метрики. Таким образом, метрика -- расстояние. Норма -- длина.

Разные нормы используются для разных вещей. Например, max-норма (inf-норма) используется для анализа выбросов в решении. Евклидова норма хорошо подходит для анализа решения в целом (так сказать, среднее по больнице). Она плохо реагирует на выбросы.

Для того, чтобы понять, насколько матрица хорошо или плоха, вводят так называемые числа обусловленности, которые можно точно посчитать аналитически. [Число обусловленности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Но в силу того, что их сложно считать (вычисление обратной матрицы очень трудоёмкая операция), часто прибегают к вычислению их оценок.

Когда я разбирался с этой темой, у меня возникал вопрос: "Почему обусловленность матрицы считается именно так?" Первый ответ -- оно хорошо характеризует величину "хорошести" матрицы. Для второго ответа нужно сказать, что часто на практике бывает так, что у одной и то же системы бывают разные правые части, т.е.

```
Ax = b
```

и

```
Ax* = c
```

В таком случае, возникает вопрос, насколько сильно будет отличаться СЛАУ, если

```
c = b + epsilon,
```

где epsilon -- бесконечно малая величина. Вот здесь и выплывает второй ответ. Берут отношение (здесь тоже Вас тоже должен постигнуть **катарсис**)

```
x*/x,
```

которое и характеризует "качество" матрицы. Если Вы хотите подробнее разобраться с этой темой, можете посмотреть в сторону теории регуляризации и теории устойчивости по Ляпунову.

Вернёмся к нашим баранам. Основным косяком, который есть в LU -- это деление очень маленького числа на очень большое. Ведь именно в результате такой операции возникают ещё меньшие числа, чем были в начале, которые уже могут чпокнуться машиной.

Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно сделать очевидную вещь -- поставить самые большие числа в числитель. Таким образом, мы получим куда лучшее решение, чем было до этого. Не так ли!? Но будьте внимательны! Вам нужно запоминать, какие вектора вы переставляли, так как при перестановке уравнений, меняется и полученный в ответе вектор! Поэтому нужно будет переставить всё в обратном порядке.

Comment: У автора нет проблем с "почти параллельными" прямыми - у него же только 1 и 0 в матрице... У автора проблемы с делением на ноль же!

Comment: Деление на ноль (почти на ноль) -- всё та же проблема обусловленности, не?

Comment: Это частный случай, который можно объяснить проще